# How does PhoneGap handle screen size changes?

Tags: android, cordova

What's the best way with using **PhoneGap** to adjust the app for screen size? 
For example, I have made an app using **HTML** and **CSS**, it looks fine on my Android but when we test it out on a small screen Android phone it looks OK, but not that good, some font and graphics need to be changed. And vice versa for scaling up to tablet size screens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhoneGap is not in charge of handling screen size changes. Your html/css should handle this. Have a look at what [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) is. Maybe try to use stuff like http://jquerymobile.com/ or http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/.

One more : http://foundation.zurb.com/